# Applovin Test Ads are not showing in android application in java

Tags: java, android, ads, applovin

i am integrating applovin ads in my app but test ads are not showing in my app even i added the line in which we add GAID but applovin test ads are not showing.

i tried this
AppLovinSdk.getInstance(context).getSettings().setTestDeviceAdvertisingIds(Arrays.asList("YOUR_GAID_HERE"));
but test ads not showing

Comment: Can you give some more context so that others can understand where you are stuck better? For instance, are you following the AppLovin SDK integration guide? If so, at which step did you run into a problem and what is the problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Add the GAIDs in Applovin dashboard, test section

Comment: Does the problem resolved ? 
I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You can Use Mediation debugger for enabling test mode

```
// use in AppController or splash screen
AppLovinSdk.getInstance(this).showMediationDebugger();
```